# Cannot connect to ejabberd web interface

Tags: web, ejabberd

Here's a link to my ejabberd.yml:
http://thecotmangroup.com/ejabberd.yml

I was in the process of installing ejabberd on a DigitalOcean instance using the instructions here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ejabberd-xmpp-server-on-ubuntu

Registering the admin user went fine.  The first snag was when it referenced "/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.cfg" which does not exist in my installation.  Perhaps that's an old reference, because it looks like they now use "ejabberd.yml" to configure.

So I did my best to edit this file correctly.  NOTE: this may be where I screwed up so any ejabberd.yml help goes to the top of the list!

Then I did:

service ejabberd restart

... and got no feedback, which I took as a good sign.

But I cannot connect to :5280/admin.  It's not that I can't log in, it's that firefox makes no connection.

I *can* ping the ip address.

I *have* opened port 5280 and verified with telnet and netstat.

I *can* see other services on this box from the open web (I quickly installed nginx to test.)

I *cannot* connect to localhost:5280 using w3m on the server itself.  So I am inclined to think that I am missing something in the config file(s).

Does anyone know anything about the new and improved ejabberd config files?  Does anyone think it's not that but something else?

Thank you.

Comment: could u share your ejabberd.yml file

Comment: Look at the log. Likely your server did not start, probably because of a syntax error in your ejabberd.yml config file.

Comment: I just posted a link to my logfile (ejabberd.yml.)  Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: I know this question is quite old, but I had the same issue and found a solution for me. So maybe it will help someone else.
try: https://localhost:5280/admin
the trick was, to use https instead of http

Comment: @HexXx Thank you for that. I've been trying to figure out what was going wrong for hours, and this finally did it.